# Does generating data from a normal with an effect added and comparing to a standard normal allow for calculation of power?

Tags: simulation, statistical-power

I generated 100 random variables from a normal with mean 1 and standard deviation 1, representing a large effect size when compared to a standard normal.

Using a test where I compare p values from the generated normal to a cut off at the 0.05 level of the standard normal, should I be able to simply count false-negatives and use that to determine power?

Answer (score 0):

Tl;dr: No, probably not.

Adopting frequentist language, this computation only computes the power for a single "alternate hypothesis" -- which is not even the "alternate hypothesis" that the population you are sampling from is 1 standard deviation from the mean, unless you intend to measure this difference with samples of size 1. Are you generating samples from this Normal distribution, or are you generating individual random variables? If you are generating individual random variables and checking their "p values" then your "alternate hypothesis" situation has sqrt(n) times the variance as a standard normal, if you want each point from your sample process to represent the mean of a sample of size n.

In other words, this computation is very unlikely to be accurate for any specific scenario. I suggest you work backwards: What is the size of difference you wish to be able to detect? What is your best approximation for the within-class variance of the group(s) you wish to compare? Then, if you really wish to simulate this (instead of doing a direct Normal calculation) you can simulate samples of size n from your 'alternate hypothesis' and compute what percent are rejected according to the "null hypothesis." Alternately, you can compute the rejection threshold for the mean at a given sample size, and use a standard Normal calculation to determine what percent of samples from your alternate hypothesis distribution will lead to rejection.

You might wish to bootstrap if, instead, you have a "prior" distribution for the alternate hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks. It's in the context of testing multiple hypotheses. I was a bit confused as I saw a guide where 900 entries were generated from a standard normal and 100 from a normal with mean 3, sd = 1, corresponding to where the null hypothesis is true and false respectively.
Alpha is set to 0.05 and the number of rejections for the first 900 entries & subsequent 100 are used to calculate the type 1 error and type 2 error/power for that instance. I think I'm misunderstanding this.. grossly.

https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mgoldman/Section0402.pdf - section 5 FYI.

Comment: Ok. That does definitely allow you to compute power in a specific instance, but is grossly simplified to be relatively useless in a power computation "in general." -that is, you'd have to take some extra steps to be able to apply this to a general power computation. For a specific scenario, it is worth taking the time to really think about what test you are computing the power for and tailoring your computations to that test specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the core of a reasonable idea, but it needs more structure in order
to be of practical use. I will try to provide some structure. If what I outline generally will work for you, then you can make the necessary modifications. If not, then please be specific about why not, and maybe one of us can suggest a somewhat different Answer.

It seems you propose to do a simulation to find the power of a two-sample test. You
mention normal data, so I suppose you may have a t test in mind. But it is not clear
what sample sizes you might use.
Also, from what you say, it is difficult to know what hypothesis you are testing and against what alternative.

**Issues that affect power.** Suppose you want to test $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2$ against $H_a: \mu_1 \ne \mu_2$ at the 5% level.
Typically, four characteristics are in tension with one another.

- Difference
  $\Delta = |\mu_1 - \mu_2|$ you need to be able to detect in order to have a useful result.
- Power of the test: the probability of Rejecting $H_0$ if there really is a difference of size $\Delta.$
- The standard deviations $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ of the two populations, whether equal or not.
- The sample sizes $n_1$ and $n_2$ you will use.

For example, for given sample sizes, difference $\Delta,$ and standard deviations,
what will be the power? If sample sizes are large, $\Delta$ is large, and standard deviations are small, you can expect relatively good power. As sample sizes decrease, $\Delta$ decreases, or standard deviations increase, the power will decrease.

Most 'power and sample size' procedures ask you to provide values for three of the
four bullets, and give you a value for the remaining one. To make things easier
it is common to dictate that $n_1 = n_2$ because this is the most efficient
allocation of sample sizes. Also, especially if a pooled t test is contemplated,
it is assumed $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ will have a common value. [You may or may not
be allowed to specify significance levels other than 5%.]

**Simulating the power of a Welch t test.** Simulation may be required if it is necessary to design an experiment with
$n_1 \ne n_2,$ or you know that $\sigma_1 \ne \sigma_2.$ Let's see how to get the
power of a Welch 2-sample t test in detecting the difference between
normally distributed populations $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_1 = 100, \sigma_1 = 10)$ and
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_2 = 110, \sigma_2 = 15)$ with sample sizes $n_1 = 20, n_2 = 30.$

We can simulate $m = 10^5 = 100\,000$ tests to these specifications. Then get P-values for all $m$ Welch tests, and finally see what proportion of the tests reject $H_0;$
that is what proportion of tests have P-values below $0.05 = 5\%.$ That will be the approximate power of the Welch 2-sample t test in the specified circumstances.

I believe this is essentially what you are proposing to do, but with enough
specified boundaries to get a useful simulated result. R code for the simulation
might be as shown below. The power is about $0.791 \pm 0.001.$ If you want larger
power, you can use larger samples---or be satisfied to detect a difference of
size perhaps $\Delta = 15,$ instead of $\Delta = 10,$ as in the simulation.

```
set.seed(2020)
n1 = 20;  n2 = 30;  mu1 = 100; mu2 = 110;  sg1 = 10; sg2 = 15
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(n1,mu1,sg1), rnorm(n2,mu2,sg2))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.79082
sd(pv <= .05)/sqrt(10^5)
[1] 0.001286178
```

*Notes about R code:*

(1) The notation `$p.val` appended to `t.test` captures only the P-value of the test.

(2) After the run, the numeric vector `pv` contains $m=10^5$ P-values.

(3) The vector `pv <= .05` is a logical vector of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s; its `mean` is the proportion of its `TRUE`s. This is the approximate P-value of the specified test.

(4) The last statement approximates the 95% margin of simulation error for the power.